# How can I install oVirt on one server?

Tags: virtualization, ovirt

I have one server.
And when I install ovirt I can open web interface at 10.0.0.10.
But, then I try instal host on 10.0.0.10 after that I can`t open 10.0.0.10

So, how I can instal ovirt-engine and host on one server?
Can you give me link to any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a single host for both engine and run vms, the supported and suggested configuration is to use Hosted Engine. 
See http://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/hosted-engine/

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official quickstart guide http://www.ovirt.org/documentation/quickstart/quickstart-guide/

This definitely works for oVirt release 3.6 and Fedora 22 Server.

After you add the host in the webgui, it deploys necessary packages and configurations on the host. One of these steps configures and starts iptables. Maybe you first need to disable iptables and reconfigure it and that's the reason why your ovirt-engine isn't available after your deployment is finished. You can read the details which ports to open for iptables in the Quickstart Guide.

If you use CentOS this post maybe also helpful http://blog.mit.bme.hu/meszaros/en/node/193

Comment: Can you please answer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655947/collecting-the-statistics-of-disk-usage-using-ovirt

Answer (score 0):

[oVirt Orb](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/ovirt-orb/) is what you are looking for, if you just want to try it out. "oVirt Orb lets you try out oVirt on your own laptop. You can test it and play with it, all without the need to manually install all the components or use multiple hosts or a storage server."

If you have shared storage available somewhere or don't mind setting it up, Hosted Engine (as Sandro mentioned) will give you an Engine Virtual Machine running on a single Host. (Hosted Engine requires NFS, iSCSI, etc.)